# Show/Make a field editable or disabled in admin based on other field's value

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am working on a Django project and want to achieve the following functionality :-

```
class XYZModel(models.Model):
   available = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   availability_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
```

So i want that **availability_date** becomes editable only if **available** is set to True, while giving values to the object in admin.
If **available** is False, **availability_date** is shown disabled...

How can i do so?...

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add some JavaScript to the change form for your XYZModel admin class. This can be done by [overriding the change form for the template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates), or by adding a [reference to the JavaScript file in a custom form class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/media/#) for your model admin.